Prepend output while streaming like foreman
I have this ruby script that I use quite often:
$stdin.each_line do |it|
  it.strip!
  eval(ARGV.first)
end

For instance:
> dir | each "Dir.chdir(it) { puts it; system('bundle') }"
code
Bundle complete! 41 Gemfile dependencies, 165 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
code-ruby
Bundle complete! 6 Gemfile dependencies, 44 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

I do this "puts it" quite often and would rather have my output be prepended by the "it".
e.g.
> dir | each "Dir.chdir(it) { system('bundle') }"
[code] Bundle complete! 41 Gemfile dependencies, 165 gems now installed.
[code] Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
[code-ruby] Bundle complete! 6 Gemfile dependencies, 44 gems now installed.
[code-ruby] Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

This is even more obvious with the parallel version:
Parallel.each($stdin.each_line.to_a) do |it|
  it.strip!
  eval(ARGV.first)
end


system('bundle') will just execute the command which then outputs to stdout on its own. To control the output, you have to capture it and rewrite each line.

@Stefan I'm really unsure how to do that

I guess I would need to create a new process with system("ruby", "-e", "...", out:)

You can override system output and add prefix for every line of output:
def system(cmd)
  rd, wr = IO.pipe
  Thread.new do
    Kernel.system(cmd, out: wr)
    wr.close
  end

  until rd.eof?
    line = rd.gets
    puts "[#{Thread.current[:prefix]}] #{line}"
  end
  rd.close
end

$stdin.each_line do |it|
  Thread.current[:prefix] = it.strip!
  eval(ARGV.first)
end

Test:
$ ls | ./each "Dir.chdir(it) { system('bundle') }"

[app1] Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
[app1] Resolving dependencies...
[app1] Fetching minitest 5.25.1
[app1] Fetching parallel 1.26.3
[app1] Fetching brakeman 6.2.1
[app1] Fetching rexml 3.3.6
[app1] Installing parallel 1.26.3
...
[app1] Fetching stimulus-rails 1.3.4
[app1] Installing rails 7.2.1
[app1] Installing stimulus-rails 1.3.4
[app1] Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 99 gems now installed.
[app1] Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
[app2] Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
[app2] Resolving dependencies...
[app2] Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 99 gems now installed.
[app2] Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
[app3] Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
[app3] Resolving dependencies...
[app3] Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 99 gems now installed.
[app3] Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Process.html#module-Process-label-File+Redirection+-28File+Descriptor-29

Update
You could run a separate process, like foreman does for each command, this way all output is redirected, and seems to work with parallel:
require "parallel"

Parallel.each($stdin.each_line.to_a) do |it|
  prefix = it.strip!
  rd, wr = IO.pipe
  pid = Process.spawn(RbConfig.ruby, "-e", %(it="#{it}"), "-e", ARGV.first, out: wr, err: wr)
  wr.close
  loop do
    if rd.eof?
      puts "[#{prefix}] process #{pid} closed"
      break
    else
      line = rd.gets
      puts "[#{prefix}] #{line}"
    end
  end
end

$ ls | ./each "Dir.chdir(it) { system('bundle'); puts 'hi' }" 

[app2] Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 99 gems now installed.
[app2] Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
[app2] hi
[app2] process 1808150 closed
[app3] Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 99 gems now installed.
[app3] Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
[app3] hi
[app3] process 1808151 closed
[app1] Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 99 gems now installed.
[app1] Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
[app1] hi
[app1] process 1808149 closed


i don't want to have to use command in my scripts

i use this my scripts a lot, especially each and parallel, so i would rather the prefixing be done with a command line option like -p or --print

thanks, but see my comment "I guess I would need to create a new process with system("ruby", "-e", "...", out:), because I can do puts, p, warn, abort, etc. also this doesn't work in parallel

I think I got a good idea of how to write what I want, I will post it here later

@Dorian separate process seems to work. see update.

Thanks that works really well, here is my version from your answer: https://gist.github.com/dorianmariecom/7e2b959c890260d3fdbc28cfa5f7e73c. Thanks a lot, I will award the 500 reputation points when i can, e.g. in 6+ hours

@Dorian in your script, doesn't read_err.gets blocks the while loop, so you're not really getting live output from read_out.gets as it comes in?

yes, i learned that by using it, at soon as there is a stderr output then the stdout gets into one block, do you have any solution for this?

@Dorian probably have to have a separate loop for read_err in a different Thread.

https://github.com/dorianmariecom/dorian-eval/blob/f5149d32082bdf6ec9517ae1e6e3e87c6094d697/lib/dorian/eval.rb#L72-L91 thanks works really well
